# Efficient way to get ip addresses based on a list of hostnames

Tags: shell, grep

I had to gather a list of IP addresses from a list of hostnames, this is what I came up with:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                
Hosts='host1 host2 host3 host4 host5 host6 host7' 

for h in $Hosts                                                                                            
do                                                                                                         
    echo "$h : " $(ping -c 1 $h | egrep -o -m 1 '\([0-9]+\.[^\(\r\n]*\)')    done
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: How do you associate each host with its corresponding IP address with that? And what is inefficient about it?

Comment: I've edited the answer with an echo to print both the host and the ip. I was just curious if there would be some special nslookup/ping syntax that could give me that information more easily for multiple hostnames.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you mean the latency gets you down, you can do them all in parallel with GNU Parallel:

```
parallel -a hosts 'echo -n {}; ping -c1 {} |egrep -o -m 1 "\([0-9]+\.[^\(\r\n]*\)"'
```

The `-a hosts` assumes you have the hostnames in a file called `hosts`.

**hosts:**

```
virgin
router
```

**Output:**

```
virgin(192.168.100.1)
router(192.168.0.1)
```

Or, if you don't want a file of hostnames, you can use your loop:

```
for h in virgin router; do 
   echo $h; 
done | parallel 'echo -n {}; ping -c1 {} |egrep -o -m 1 "\([0-9]+\.[^\(\r\n]*\)"'
```

Alternatively, have a look in the `arp` cache...

```
arp router
router.asus.com (192.168.0.1) at 8:60:6e:ba:17:c8 on en0 ifscope [ethernet]

arp virgin
virgin (192.168.100.1) -- no entry
```

Comment: Dude, that's enough! :) Your answer achieved the maximum level of awesomeness!

Comment: Excellent! I love it when a plan comes together :-)