# cocoa-applescript - background process shell command

Tags: shell, ping, stderr, applescript-objc

I have built a program which involves pinging specified IP addresses to tell whether they are active or not.

```
repeat for IPaddress in allIPaddresses
try
    do shell script "ping -o -t 1 -c 1 " & IPaddress
    set goodIPs to (goodIPs & IPaddress) -- where goodIPs is a list of online IPs
end try
end repeat
```

The problem is that it will cycle through a **lot** of IPs if needed and the interface freezes up while it is pinging - so if you needed to hit the "Quit" button, you can't and Force Quitting is the only way to stop it. After searching around for how to run the command as a background process, I found the most common answer (eg https://discussions.apple.com/thread/323661?start=0&tstart=0) was to add:

```
> /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

or slight (but similar output) variations of that to the end of the shell command. But that involves sending the stderr away from the application, and since my program *needs* the stderr to tell if the ping was successful or not, this is not an option. Does anyone know how to keep stderr normal but move the command to a background process so that the interface works as normal?

Comment: Consider pinging, say 64, hosts in parallel with a 2-second timeout. It'll take around 2 seconds... http://stackoverflow.com/a/25790774

Comment: thanks for the reply and that would be amazing, how do you use 'parallel' in a command, I tried using it but it said that parallel is not a command? Additionally, there is no for loop in my script, just a repeat loop for each IP address. I'll update my question to show

Comment: The easiest way to install GNU Parallel, or *lots* of other interesting Open Source software, is to use `homebrew` as your package manager since Apple do not provide one. You go to http://brew.sh and download the one-line installer and run it in Terminal. Then you can install GNU Parallel with `brew install parallel`.

Comment: Thanks, I have home-brew and I'll install that, but I assume that it will only work with computers which have that installed, meaning less portability. Is there a solution that does not require a home-brew download, or is there a way to include the necessary files into the app itself?

Comment: What is *"a lot"* of addresses - 60? 8000?

Comment: 255 would be average (x.x.x.1-255) but it also has a 'favourites' section and if you were really committed you could have more than that - 255 would be the usual maximum though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

If you want to ping one at a time no matter how slow and show off the slow progress with a progress bar ;-)

```
ping -o -t 1 -c 1 192.168.0.1 > /dev/null 2>&1 && echo up
```

This will output `up` if the host is up, and nothing if it is down. Or if you want it to output `down` if the host is down:

```
ping -o -t 1 -c 1 192.168.0.1 > /dev/null 2>&1 && echo up || echo down
```

**Second Answer**

You could do it in the shell with a little script like this. Save it as `pinger`, and then make it executable with

```
chmod +x pinger
```

Then in your Applescript, you would need to write the list of IP addresses you want checked into a file called `iplist.txt` and use

```
do shell script /path/to/wherever/pinger
```

and grab its output.

You can try it in the Terminal with

```
./pinger
```

Here is the script.

```
#!/bin/bash
# pinger
#
# Remove results of any previous runs, but suppress any error messages
rm hostup-* 2> /dev/null

# Ping all hosts in "iplist.txt" ...
# ... and create file "hostup-<IP ADDRESS>" for any that are up
while read ip; do
   ( ping -o -t 1 -c 1 $ip > /dev/null 2>&1 && touch hostup-$ip ) &
done < iplist.txt

wait # for all pings to finish

# Now go back through and see who answered
while read ip; do
   filename="hostup-$ip"
   if [ -f "$filename" ]; then
      rm $filename
      echo $ip
   fi
done < iplist.txt
```

**Précis of Original Answer**

Use GNU Parallel...

Comment: That is a nice solution, the only problem is that, since it is still a shell script, the interface freezes up - also, the progress bar no longer increments since the repeat loop is no longer there (my fault, I didn't mention the progress bar). This is much faster, but is there a solution, however slow, that fits into a repeat loop (i.e. one IP per loop) that won't freeze the interface, will allow progress bar advancing and is portable? Sorry, I know I'm being picky and I'm asking a lot.

Comment: Thank you so much, that last solution is perfect for the app. In addition, that script is good for mass pinging from terminal so I might use that in the future. Thanks again