# Pinging mutiple IP simultaneously using BASH

Tags: multithreading, bash, shell, ping

I have a shell script in which I am trying to simultaneously  ping multiple IP's at the same time

```
#!/bin/sh

#-------------------------------
#Decleration of IP Address
#-------------------------------

IP_linux32='135.24.229.174'
IP_linux64='135.24.228.128'
IP_freeBSD32='135.24.228.104'
IP_freeBSD64='135.24.228.129'
DUMMY='135.24.229.0'

count_linux32=$( ping -c2 -i5 $IP_linux32 |grep icmp* ) &
count_linux64=$( ping -c2 -i5 $IP_linux64 |grep icmp* ) &
count_freeBSD32=$( ping -c2 -i5 $IP_freeBSD32 |grep icmp* ) &
count_freeBSD64=$( ping -c2 -i5 $IP_freeBSD64 |grep icmp* ) &
dummy=$( ping -c2 -i5 $DUMMY |grep icmp* ) &

sleep 6

if [[ ( "$count_linux32" -eq 0 && "$count_linux64" -eq 0 ) ]]
 then
        echo "Linux is up"
 else
        echo "Linux not up"
fi
if [[ ( "$count_freeBSD32" -eq 0  && "$count_freeBSD64" -eq 0 ) ]]
 then
        echo "BSD is up"
 else
        echo "BSD si not up"
fi
if [[ "$dummy" -eq 0 ]]
 then
        echo "Dummy is up"
 else
        echo "Dummy is not up"
fi
```

The Dummy is false IP which should fail according to the code but still I am getting "Dummy is up" and not "Dummy is not up".

Is there anything which I am doing wrong.

I tried referring to lot of solutions but still I am not able to figure it out

Comment: Don't know if that's all, but replace `sleep 6` by `wait` - in any case.

Comment: `x=3 &` runs the command in a subshell, so the variable assignment doesn't happen in the context of the shell script.

Comment: How do I get the return status of the ping command from the subshell ?

Comment: Have a look here... http://stackoverflow.com/a/25790774/2836621

Answer (score 1):

**Updated as per comment:**

Make a list of your ips in a file, say, `list.txt`. It may look something like:

```
192.168.0.21
192.168.0.53
.
.
.
192.168.0.137
```

Then you may use the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Program name: ping_all_ips.sh

date

cat /path/to/list.txt |  while read output
do
    ping -c 1 "$output" > /dev/null
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "node $output is up" 
    else
    echo "node $output is down"
    fi
done
```

That will give you the status of your nodes. you may even store the result in a file `./ping_all_ips.sh > ping_log.txt` or schedule the task using `crontab`.

---

**For Simultaneous Pinging**

*As per recent comment*

---

For the *real* simultaneous thing, you have to use languages that support `multithreading` like `Cuda`, I suppose. But for all practical purposes, the following code will tell you if all nodes are up or not.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Program name: ping_all_ips.sh

date

cat ip.txt | xargs -n 1 -I ^ -P 50 ping -c2 ^ > log.txt

if grep -q 'Unreachable' log.txt
then
  echo "All hosts are not up"
else
  echo "All hosts are up"
fi
```

Comment: I want to ping multiple IP in parallel, your solution is for only single IP

Comment: Updated the answer,please check.

Comment: This logic, as I understand is sequential, every time only single IP gets pinged every time. I want to ping each IP in a different background process. The implementation of this sample script is i ping the IPs in background until all the IPs are up and do some operation next.

Comment: As far as we are not using `multithreading` , we execute commands sequentially only, but for our purposes we can *simulate* parallelism to some extent by `xargs`. The above code should do.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `nmap`, but it also tests sequentially.

```
nmap -sP ADDR1 ADDR2 ADDR3
```