# How to ping a list of ip and rank result by average time (printing ip and avg time only) timeout at the bottom

Tags: bash

I have an ip list file: iplistALL.txt

I want to ping all ip in that list and output a file nemed: iplistAVGT.txt

Inside iplistAVGT.txt I want all pinged ip listed along with average ping only, each on one line in order of average time from lower to higher and those who timed out at the end.

Using bash please.

So far I do this:

`` for i in `cat iplistALL.txt` ; do ping -c1 $i 2>&1 | tee >> ping-output.txt; done ``

But I get too many info I just want the ip and time on one line. also for some reason the last one gets truncated. And they are not listed in order by time

Comment: Also post what you've tried so far after you take a quick look at [mcve]

Comment: This may give you some ideas... https://stackoverflow.com/a/25790774/2836621

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your ping-output.txt looks like this, for example:

```
PING 10.0.0.1 (10.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=49 time=110.183 ms
--- 10.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 110.183/110.183/110.183/0.000 ms
PING 10.0.0.2 (10.0.0.2): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=0 ttl=48 time=106.966 ms

--- 10.0.0.2 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 106.966/106.966/106.966/0.000 ms
```

You can use awk to pick out the IP and avg round trip time as follows:

```
awk ' 
/ping statistics/ { 
  ip=$2
}  
 /round-trip/ { 
  split( $4, array, "/" ) 
  print ip,array[2]
}' ping-output.txt
```

to yield:

```
10.0.0.1 110.183
10.0.0.2 106.966
```